# pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet fails when S3 is the destination

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I'm having a Pandas dataframe which I'm trying to save as parquet file into S3:

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame({'field': [1,2,3]})
dftest.to_parquet("s3://bucket_name/test.parquet", engine='pyarrow', 
compression='gzip')
```

I'm getting : "FileNotFoundError: bucket_name/test.parquet"

Comment: try `dftest.to_parquet(r"s3://bucket_name/test.parquet", engine='pyarrow', 
compression='gzip')`

Comment: Thank you Chris, but it didn't solve the issue, keep getting "FileNotFoundError: bucket_name/test.parquet"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I still couldn't make pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet approach to work with S3, I did find different solution which seems to work:

```
import s3fs
from fastparquet import write
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
myopen = s3.open
write('s3://bucketname/test.parquet', dftest, compression='GZIP', open_with=myopen)
```